# Get php var inside javascript file (making plugin)

Tags: plugins, php, wp-enqueue-script

I was making a plugin and I have a javascript file where I want to take some options saved in the database to show well the function.

So I have this:

```
function wp_home(){

    wp_enqueue_script( 'some-name-1', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js', '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'some-name-2', plugins_url( 'assets/jquery.something.css', __FILE__ ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'some-name-3', plugins_url( 'assets/jquery.something.js', __FILE__ ), '1.0.0', true );



        global $table_prefix;
        $dbh = new wpdb( DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST );
        $table = $table_prefix.'options';
        $qd = "SELECT option_value FROM $table WHERE option_name = 'description'";

        $description = $dbh->get_results( $query_link );

        $description = $description[0]->option_value;

      //HERE I HAVE THE STRING OF $description AND I WANT TO PASS INSIDE TO CUSTOM-JS-PHP

     wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-name-js', plugins_url( 'assets/custom-js.php', __FILE__ ), '1.0.0', true );

}
```

The file custom-js.php it's like this:

```
     <?php header("Content-type: text/javascript"); ?>


        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.showBox({
                message: '<?php echo $description; ?>',
            });
        });
```

How I can take the $description? If I put the javascript inside wp_home() it doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: As a sidenote, you should route all requests through WordPress, never make direct calls to PHP files inside your plugin or theme from the browser, be it for AJAX, form submissions, etc, it's a huge security headache

Comment: its a js file with a php extension nice :)))

Comment: if you are using a php file why don't you just put the select query in it not in  the in_home function?

Comment: @TomJNowell isn't it also an issue that WordPress doesn't respect encapsulation? It's a big shame that WordPress can't pass the JS file the parameters as a JSON string or similar to reduce the chance of a namespace clash.

Comment: @dewd you mean via something like `wp_localize_script`? That's more than doable, see the top answer

Comment: @TomJNowell Unofrtunately, `wp_localize_script` only allows the attachment of objects to the global `window` object. Since javascript can be written out via PHP, a better solution might be to allow such a script to have direct access to the WordPress API. That way any server variables could be encapsulated within the script itself protecting any `window` pollution issues. Much in the same way that is is best to build plugins within an OO environment to avoid clashes within the WordPress environment.

Comment: @dewd you mean the REST API? Javascript and PHP don't run on the same machine, one is client side, the other is server side so you can't just pass PHP functions back and forth into JS as you describe, else there'd be a huge amount of back and forth and resources wasted. You have to bundle data with the page or request it via the REST API, it's the same in any other system

Comment: I should point out I've been a full stack developer for 20 years, just so you know I know client/server achitecture. It's possible to load `<script type="text\javascript" src="/foo.php" ></script>` : parses script as PHP on the server side, javascript on the client side. Server side, the script has access to the full PHP API, but not the Wordpress API. This makes sense for security puposes. REST API is a good idea. Just return JSON to load in script.  However, It is that is conceivable that Wordpress would have a method to load server vars encapsulated into a script without this workaround.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [wp_localize_script()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to pass php variables to javascript.  You create an array in php and then pass it to the function as the third parameter.  It will come through as an object you name with the second parameter.

First, register the script.

`wp_register_script( 'custom-name-js', plugins_url( 'assets/custom-js.php', __FILE__ ) );`

Second, build your array and run wp_localize.

```
$my_array = array( 'description' => $description[0]->option_value );
wp_localize_script( 'custom-name-js', 'js_object_name', $my_array );
```

Finally, you enqueue your script.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-name-js' );
```

Then, in your js file, you will have a js object available named js_object_name (or whatever you pass as the second parameter to wp_localize_script) with a property of description.

```
js_object_name.description
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this function: `wp_localize_script( $handle, $name, $data );`

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script for documentation.

As the codex says:

> Though localization is the primary use, it can be used to make any data available to your script that you can normally only get from the server side of WordPress.

I had to use it for translation / localization, but it looks like it can help you "inject" your dynamic value into the javascript.