# How to pass value from WordPress to Javascript

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, javascript

`validateFile` function is triggered when user upload image to Media Library.

How do I pass `$file` to `php_vars` ? So that I can manipulate the `php_vars` value inside `validation.js`

```
$myArray = array();

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'registerValidationScript'); 
function registerValidationScript() {
    global $myArray;
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_js_library', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/validation.js' );
    wp_localize_script( 'my_js_library', 'php_vars', $myArray);
};

add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'validateFile' );
function validateFile( $file ){
    array_push($myArray, $file);
    return $file;
}
```

** Edit **

I think this question is bit different with possible duplication.

Reason is, I'm trying to get PHP variable that only available after 'post back'. Meaning, after user upload the picture to Media Library. Hence the usage of `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` hook.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get php var inside javascript file (making plugin)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/225802/get-php-var-inside-javascript-file-making-plugin)

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: In that case you can't use the localization. You need to directly interact with the media uploaded. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17668899/9159152) is a useful link.